# Kafka SSL Connection refused: no further information

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I´m wrestling with setting up Kafka SSL between Kafka Server and Spring (Boot) Kafka Client.
I have a working Kafka Server with SSL as documented here: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_ssl

```
listeners=SSL://test.test.de:9093
# ssl
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
ssl.keystore.location=/home/kafka/ssl/server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=secret
ssl.key.password=secret
ssl.truststore.location=/home/kafka/ssl/server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=secret
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
ssl.secure.random.implementation=SHA1PRNG
```

I set up a Spring Boot Library APP with Spring Kafka. These are the producer configs:

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "test.test.de:9093");
props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 0);
props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1);
props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432);
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL");
props.put("ssl.keystore.location", "C:\\dev\\tmp\\ssl\\client.keystore.jks");
props.put("ssl.truststore.location", "C:\\dev\\tmp\\ssl\\client.truststore.jks");
props.put("ssl.keystore.password", "secret");
props.put("ssl.truststore.password", "secret");
props.put("ssl.key.password", "secret");
props.put("ssl.enabled.protocols", "TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1");
props.put("ssl.keystore.type", "JKS");
props.put("ssl.truststore.type", "JKS");
```

When i´m sending a messsage via `kafkaTemplate.sendDefault` i get this exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:589) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:839) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.finishConnect(SslTransportLayer.java:137) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:220) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:530) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:549) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:324) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

**EDIT:**
Some further debug logs:

```
2020-07-16 13:28:06.204 DEBUG 12516 --- [ad | producer-1] 
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2020-07-16 13:28:06.204  WARN 12516 --- [ad | producer-1] 
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (test.test.de/192.192.192.192:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2020-07-16 13:28:06.204  WARN 12516 --- [ad | producer-1] 
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker test.test.de:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2020-07-16 13:28:06.305 DEBUG 12516 --- [ad | producer-1] 
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initialize connection to node test.test.de:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
2020-07-16 13:28:06.305 DEBUG 12516 --- [ad | producer-1] 
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating connection to node test.test.de:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) using address test.test.de/192.192.192.192
2020-07-16 13:28:08.331 DEBUG 12516 --- [ad | producer-1] 
o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection with test.test.de/192.192.192.192 disconnected
```

I don´t know what this is all about.
I can´t find error details neither on the server side nor on the client side.
I can´t evaluate if the error is a invalid SSL handshake or something else.

Comment: probably client's key should be placed into kafka's keystore and vice versa

Comment: could you please go into detail about this? Which key? Where to put?

Comment: So you already have a keystore set on Kafka server, right? have you tried disabling client authentication? (turn off "ssl.client.auth"). From my Java experience, Java client needs to have the server's certificate in its truststore, prior to connecting to it. In case of Kafka client, seems that is not needed, at least from what I have read in the docs. You may try to export certificate (.pem) out of server's keystore and import it into client's truststore, and re-check the connection (and disable client authentication for now)

Comment: `Connection refused` is down at the TCP level; it has nothing to do with SSL - it simply means there is nothing listening on port 9093 on `test.test.de`.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve just found an answer myself. Thanks for your help. As Gary Russell suggested rightly there was no SSL error. It seemed to me that the client could not reach the server for some strange reasons (ping was working).

So it turned out that on the (debian) (kafka) server in its /etc/hosts file the entry for test.test.de was set to 127.0.1.1. I changed that to the current IP Address and it is working now.
Since i am not a sysadmin i don´t know why there was this IP setting. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried another solution which is working too:

- leave above `/etc/hosts` with `127.0.1.1 test.test.de test`
- set the `listeners` in kafka´s `server.config` to `listeners=SSL://:9093`

On debian systems, the reason for 127.0.1.1 is stated here:
https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_hostname_resolution
and here:
http://bugs.debian.org/719621

I have two options:

1. So using the dns `test.test.de` in the listener config won´t work (for the client connection) as long as you have it assigned to 127.0.1.1. If you give the dns `test.test.de` its ip address obtained from any dhcp system (which should stay static usually) the listener config is working with `listeners=SSL://test.test.de:9093`
2. If you leave out the host.name setting on the listener config you can also leave the dns in the /etc/hosts set to 127.0.1.1.

I don´t know why, but this seems to solve my client-server kafka communication error with ssl.